# Does drinking beer help to cure a hangover?

Tags: physiology, alcohol, beer

It's been a long-known saying that drinking beer cures hangover. It is said that a hangover is your body craving for alcohol, so drinking a beer helps the body.

Is it true?

Comment: The problem is that many people making that claim (that I've seen) are chronic drinkers, and have a hard time separating *hangover* from *withdrawal*.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Is your question "Does the hair-of-the-dog cure hangovers?" This question is a bit confusing as it stands, because the answer, as I understand it, isn't about beer or "cravings". Do you have a reference to someone making the claim?

Comment: @Oddthinking oh, I didn't know about the "hair-of-the-dog". Since wikipedia answered my question, I guess I should delete this question?